# Obtener los datos de varios inputs nuevo con VueJS dentro de methods

Tags: jquery, vue.js, entrada

Tengo ese problema. Estoy haciendo un sistema para la facultad y decidí hacerlo con Vue. Mis conocimientos no son mucho en Vue, pero voy muy bien hasta ahora... EL código me anda perfectamente, por lo que tambien uso jQuery para algunas cosas que no sepa de VueJS y para algunos plugins (Sé que no es necesario, pero para aprendizaje decidí usar los dos).

En fin, estoy en una parte de agregar Cursos, donde hay un botón de "Agregar nuevo horario" (porque se pueden agregar varios profesores para diferentes horarios en el mismo dia) que agregar el siguiente numero de un contador a una lista con `.push()` y esa lista e iterada por `v-for` de Vue.

Pero una vez obtenido todos los datos cuando deseo obtener los valores de los nuevos inputs agregados no me salen. Sale undefined o HtmlCollections(0).

Eso es en methods > save(). Intenté obtener los datos con jQuery pero tampoco anda :(

```js
var vueModal = new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 1,
      limit: 1,
      data: [1]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(){
    if( this.limit > 4 ){
        alert('No puedes agregar mas')
        return;
      }

      this.count++,
      this.limit++;

      this.data.push( this.count );
    },
    
    remove: function(){
      this.$delete( this.data, ( this.data.length - 1 ) );
      this.limit--;
    },
  
    save: function(){
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('course-teacher-box');

        console.dir( elements )


        $('.course-teacher-box').each(function(){

          var val = $( this ).find('input').val();

          console.dir( val );

        })
    }
  
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="vue">
<div class="row" class="course-teacher-box" v-for="dataItem in data" :data="dataItem">
<hr />
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
<label for="course-cover">Profesor</label>
<select class="form-control" id="course-teacher" required=""> 
<option value="Juan">Juan</option>
<option value="José">José</option>
<option value="Maria">Maria</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3 row">
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
<label for="course-title">Hora de inicio</label>
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="course-start" placeholder="Solo números, ejemplo: 5.4" value="" required="">
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
<label for="course-title">Hora de salida</label>
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="course-end" placeholder="Solo números, ejemplo: 5.4" value="" required="">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="text-center mb-4 row" style="width:60%;margin:0 auto;">
<hr/>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
<a href="#" @click="add()" class="btn btn-info" title="Agregar nuevo"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Agregar nuevo</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
<a href="#" @click="remove()" class="btn btn-danger" title="Remover último"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remover último</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
<a href="#" @click="save()" class="btn btn-danger" title="Remover último"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Save</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Tambien utilizo bootstrap, pero mas que todo es solo el CSS.

Quisiera que cuando le de a `Save()` me muestre todos los datos de los inputs. Gracias

Comment: Hola Jonathan! Te sugiero que elijas entre jQuery o Vue.js porque cada uno tiene un enfoque diferente y solo te va a dar problemas usar ambos en la misma app.

Comment: Ok esta bien, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Usá v-model en tus inputs para obtener el valor de los mismos. [Acá](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) te dejo la documentación oficial lo cual también te muestra un ejemplo.

Una vez que agregues los v-model a tus input, reinicia esos atributos.

```
<input v-model="algo" />

// ---------------------

data: function () {
      return {
        algo: ''
      }
      // Luego usas this.algo para obtener su valor. o {{ algo }} en el lado html
     }
```

Comment: Entiendo. Lo he usado, pero verás que tengo 5 inputs que pueden ser agregados o modificados, como enlazar cada inputs con un modelo? Puedo tener data: { input1 = '', input2 = '', ..., input5 ='' } Pero cuando elimine el input con el modelo input3 como vuelvo a establecer un nuevo input con ese modelo?

Comment: No logro entender lo que me tratas de explicar. Para obtener los valores de los input es necesario crear un formulario para enviar esos datos por POST, sino podes enviarlos por GET. Yo uso v-model para obtener el valor de los input pero los input están dentro de un formulario, lo unico que hago para que el formulario no se envie cuando doy click a un botón es usar el prevent de VUE

Answer (score 0):

puedes guardar los valores en un arreglo y usarlo en los v-model de los inputs dinamicos, de esa manera, sera mas facil de manejar

```js
const vue = new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: function () {
    return {
      inputs: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addInput: function(){
      this.inputs.push({result:null})
    },
    remove: function(i){
      this.inputs.splice(i,1);
    },
    save: function(){
      console.log(this.inputs);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="vue">
  <button @click="addInput">Agregar</button>
  <button @click="save">guardar</button>
  <div v-for="(field, i) in inputs">
    <input v-model="field.result" type="text">
    <button @click="remove(i)">eliminar</button>
  </div>
  

</div>
```